# Does this site need to be more sensitive of other religions?

Tags: discussion

The answer https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/75413/47406 twice says:

> [...] hypocrisy of the religious Jews in question.

It implies that the rabbis at the time of Christ's life accepted that John was sent from God and just refused to say so, ignoring the fact that it goes against Judaism. There are many Jewish arguments against this, and Christians are entitled to have a different opinion.

I'm not concerned with the religious truth of either side, but with my personal safety. I have had a Christian who wanted to do me physical harm say "You killed Jesus" (meaning that I, as a Jew, was literally responsible for Jesus' crucifixion), and use passages from the Bible to support his stance.

I don't think answers should be critical of other religions, or their leaders when they're acting in alignment with their religion and therefore by implication the religion too, as it leads to friction and can have serious, real life, negative consequences.

My concern is that the answer is anti-Semitic. Should users be sensitive to how their posts could be interpreted by other religions? I have friends who are Christian, atheist, Jewish, Buddhist, Muslim, Sikh, etc., I enjoy learning about different belief systems, and I often find interesting questions here. I'd like to think that everyone is welcome here, even if their beliefs are different, as long as they're respectful.

Comment: '... _in question_ ...'. The answer gave a reason for historical events. The answer is not making wide-sweeping stereo-typical judgments on the entire race. The particular people in question are only identified by being Jews. Therefore it is 'the Jews in question'.

Comment: Agreed with @NigelJ that this is historical, not anti-Semitic.  I have Christian friends and know quite a few churches who bless the Jews, quoting [Gen 12:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+12%3A3&version=ESV).  They don't blame modern Jews for what happened 2000 years ago.  The Catholic church even published a document [Nostra aetate](http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_decl_19651028_nostra-aetate_en.html) to guide the millions Catholics for proper perspective on the modern Jews.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not. This site's goal is to catalog all Christian beliefs and practices. A few points:

1. There's a lot of Christian beliefs and some of them are generally offensive.
2. Some beliefs are offensive to other Christians.
3. Some beliefs are offensive to Muslims
4. Some believe are offensive to Jews

If you're going to wade in to the vast array of Christian beliefs, prepare to learn things you don't like. You're going to have to leave your judgments at the door and approach this scientifically, that is, with objectivity and inquisitive apathy.

---

Regarding this specific post, I think your interpretation is off base. The Jews referenced in the post are pretty obviously *only* the Jews in the story. There's absolutely no justification to say it's referring to all Jews. Further, the interpretation that the Jewish leaders of Jesus' time were indeed hypocrites and not serving the religious needs of their people is one of the few nearly universal Christian beliefs.

As to your personal experience with some genuine hatred, I'm sorry you've had to deal with it, but I believe crazies will always exist and that the post in question doesn't help them propagate. You can be confident that genuine hate is quickly and roundly dealt with on this site. Such tone is antithetical to objectivity and inquisitive apathy.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this we all need to be sensitive of other religions and our own religions.

Answers are required to represent the viewpoint asked for, it's not necessary for an answerer to make commentary on that viewpoint positive or negative.  If you find that that answer doesn't represent the Evangelical Protestant viewpoint, then flag it and we'll do something about it.  If you don't like the answer vote it down.

But if you were to flag it as unfriendly or unkind, I'd have a hard time finding your meaning there. Jesus calls [lots of people hypocrites](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0839/2/KI.HTM) and for hypocrites to not act hypocritical would be... odd.